# Toast or string error

Tags: java, android, string, toast

I want to show a message to the user that the max limit is 10k.
My code:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.max_limit+"10000", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

If I delete the *R.string.max_limit+* part it shows **10000** and when I delete the "10000" part it shows **Max limit** but when I put them together the outcome is this message "21355843649".

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use a string resource and the integer instead of consolidating them into one entity?

Comment: Translation of the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using :

```
String result = getResources().getString(R.string.max_limit);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result+"10000", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: this shows Max limit 100010000 so just delete the 1000 in the first line

Comment: Yes sorry just noticed that

Answer (score 1):

You could also modify your string to this

```
<string name="max_limit">max limit is %1$d.</string>
```

Then use `getString` with an overload that uses the string as a format string like this

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.max_limit, 10000), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

See [String Resources - Formatting and Styling](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling) for more info